# Getting error while using copy data wizard

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are using copy data wizard of data factory to migrate the data from on premise mongo db server to Azure SQL. While doing so, for one of the table we are facing issue with data buffer size, as this particular table contains big text values

Even at the time of preview we are getting error as below

[Error at time of preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Iao.png)

> Error when processing request: Unknown error from wrapper. 'Type=,Message=SUCCESS_WITH_INFO [01004] [Microsoft][ODBC] (10160) String Data right trunction: String data is too big for the output data buffer and has been truncated.,Source=,' activityId: 2ec717e2-5f0a-4fe4-bebc-a68af0d23a69

We ignored it and went on to do migration, and we still got that error, but little more information as below

> Copy activity met an internal service error. For more information, provide this message to customer support. ErrorCode: 8601 GatewayNodeName=server name,ErrorCode=SystemErrorOdbcWrapperError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Unknown error from wrapper.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Interop.OdbcException,Message=SUCCESS_WITH_INFO [01004] [Microsoft][ODBC] (10160) String data right truncation: String data is too big for the output data buffer and has been truncated.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Wrapper,'.

I tried to increase the writeBatchSize for the sink to 1000000, and also increased writeBatchTimeout to 00:05:00. But it was of no help.

Please let us know how to tackle this issue

Answer (score 0):

After contacting microsoft, we found out that this happened due to limitation of their mongodb driver. They support only upto 130k characters for a value to be inserted to a field of a tuple. If it exceeds 130k character it would give above error